# How to use raspberry pi to remotely view a mac

Tags: vnc

I've got an old Mac Pro that we use as our media centre (watch netfix, dvds that I've ripped, home movies etc). It's old and noisy so I bought a raspberry pi B+ and would like to move the mac into a closet. I'd like to stick the raspberry pi on the back of the tv and wirelessly connect to my mac. I want to mirror my macs screen on the tv using the rpi.

I have itapvnc on my mac and I've allowed screen sharing on my mac. I've installed ssvnc on my rpi.  My goal is to have the rpi start up and automatically share the macs screen but I'll settle for just seeing the screen right now.

I'm not afraid of using the command line but in all honesty I just follow the recipes and cut and paste. I'm learning as I go along.

Can a guiding hand point me in the right direction?

BTW most of the postings about vncs and mirroring are about how to mirror the rpi, I'm trying to do the opposite.

Comment: You don't tell us much about what you have tried. Have you installed a VNC client on the Pi? (Note I haven't tried this myself, I usually use my Mac to access the Pi). While not directly related to your question I suggest you install `netatalk` on the Pi. This is an `AFP` program which lets the Mac and Pi discover each other and address the Mac by MacSharingName.local. Check the file sharing options on the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable a password on the Mac for VNC viewers

System Preferences > Sharing > Screen Sharing > Computer Settings

[image: System Preferences > Sharing]

Then on the Raspberry Pi start the VNC client:

`ssnvcviewer 192.168.1.5`